# JavaScript - Rotate div with a class by x degree

Tags: javascript, html, rotation

I wrote the following code. I want to rotate the div - which has a class of .hour-hand - with an angle which is stored in a variable called randomvar.

However, I can't rotate it even using a simple "100" degree value... What am I missing? Thank you very much for your help!

document.getElementByClass("hour-hand").style.transform = "rotate(100)";

Comment: It's actually getElementsByClassName()

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `deg`. You should write `document.querySelector(".hour-hand").style.transform = "rotate(100deg)";`

Comment: GetElementByClass is not valid function

Comment: @Manjunath agree, fixed